# thymeleaf - how to fix header fragment overlapping content and sidebar menu?

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

On my app I have a `default.html` fragment that pieces all other fragments. It is transcribed bellow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">

<head th:include="fragments/common :: commonFragment">
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link rel="shortcut-icon" th:href="@{/assets/img/favicon.png}" type="image/x-icon" />
<title th:text="#{app.name}"> </title>
</head>
<body>
    <section th:id="defaultFragment" th:fragment="defaultFragment">
        <section id="header" th:replace="fragments/header :: headerFragment"></section>
        <div id="sidebar-and-content" class="main-container container-fluid">
            <div th:replace="fragments/sidebar :: sidebarFragment"></div>
            <div class="page-container">
                <div class="page-content">
                    <div class="page-body" >
                        <div layout:fragment="content"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <section th:replace="fragments/footer :: footerFragment"></section>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

What I have noticed is that the header fragment section overlaps the following section. If I comment out the header section, the next div (id="sidebar-and-content") is rendered at the top of the page. When I uncomment it (id="header") the next div is also rendered at the top of the page and 'beneath' the header.

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by reverting to an earlier version...

```
<body>
    <div th:id="defaultFragment" th:fragment="defaultFragment">
        <div th:replace="fragments/header :: headerFragment"></div>
        <div class="main-container container-fluid">
            <div class="page-container">
                <div th:replace="fragments/sidebar :: sidebarFragment"></div>
                <div class="page-content">
                    <div class="page-body">
                        <div layout:fragment="content"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div th:replace="fragments/footer :: footerFragment"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

All is good and working as should.